# Drupal page with non-Drupal microsites off same path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, drupal, url-rewriting

I'm trying to figure out what sort of htaccess rules or directory setup I need to have a Drupal page created with page manager and separately have a collection of static pages or micro-sites off of the same path.

For example, I'd like to have `example.com/parent` as a Drupal panels page created with page manager. I'd then like to have `example.com/parent/microsite-1`, `example.com/parent/microsite-2`, etc., as non-Drupal pages.

Right now I have the parent directory in the root of my Drupal installation and I get a 403 when trying to access the page, but I can access the micro-sites. Is this setup possible, or do I need to rename the parent directory and set up redirects?

I have the default Drupal htaccess file in place with the following setting preventing the current parent directory from listing the contents:

```
    # Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
    Options -Indexes
```

**Update re: accepted answer**

I've added the following alias to httpd.conf:

```
Alias /parent/microsite-1 /path/to/drupal/root/microsite-directory/microsite-1
```

My microsites now live in Drupal root under `microsite-directory`, and are accessible, as is the Drupal page `example.com/parent`.

Comment: I think you need to post the contents of your existing .htaccess file. From your question (and without knowing the Drupal config) it's not at all obvious why you would get a 403 in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is the [Apache **Alias** directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

Something like the following should work:

```
Alias /parent/microsite-1 /path/to/microsite/root
```

However, that does not work on .htaccess context. For that to work, you could try simply putting the microsites inside of the Drupal folder (which I would not recommend), or use a symbolic link from within Drupal to said microsite folders.

Comment: Although the microsites appear to work OK; it's the "Drupal panels page" that doesn't?

Comment: @w3d Correct, it's the Drupal page, which has the same path as the parent directory, that is being overridden by the directory content.

Comment: @Peter-Carrero To clarify - you're recommending moving the parent directory out of the Drupal root directory, then creating an alias directive?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this module in the past successfully for some enterprise customers:

https://www.drupal.org/project/minisite

It will do the heavy lifting, you (or site builders) just need to upload the microsite